# Unity. Event Trigger

Tags: c#, unity3d

Сделал движение под ПК (WASD),
Хочу сделать управление для мобил, путем добавление кнопок (влево, вправо, вверх, вниз)
Добавил картинки на UI. дал им Event Trigger. При однократном нажатии на кнопку срабатывает 1 раз, а при игре на ПК зажимая "W", Obj двигается непрерывно. Как сделать, что бы при ЗАжатии на кнопку на UI, движение тоже было непрерывное. (Сейчас если зажать, то obj двинется 1 раз и остановится)

Пробовал разные методы в самом EventTriggere. Проще управление переписать или я что-то делаю не так?

[image: Методы передвижения]
[image: EventTrigger]

Comment: PointerDown вызывается единожды при нажатии, не так ли?

Comment: Смотрел гайды, все зажимают и у них работает именно зажатие

Comment: Выяснил что проблема в FixedUpd 
протестировал на 2d проекте, была такая же ошибка пока не прописал  FixedUpd, Встает вопрос. что тогда писать тут?

void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();    
    }
 
   public void Lb()
    {
        speedX = -HorSpeed;
    }
 
    public void Rb()
    {
        speedX = HorSpeed;
    }
 
  public void bU()
    {
        speedX = 0;
    }
 
    private void FixedUpdate()
    {
        transform.Translate(speedX,0 ,0);
    }
 
}

Comment: как новому участнику объясняю вам **ГЛАВНОЕ** священное правило: код текстом. Текстом, а не картинкой. Кстати, не мучайте людей которым придется читать ваш код, называйте методы понятно: OnRightArrowButton, OnButtonReleaved, а еще лучше что-то типа MoveRight, MoveUp, StopMove etc. Потому что я, например, на несколько секунд завис, увидев методы OnUpBtn() и OnBtnUp(). Можно ли точно сказать, что они делают, без знания кода в них? Нельзя? А нужно!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{
   
    [SerializeField] Vector3 moveDirection; // задать скорость движения
    Rigidbody rb;
    bool touch;  // нажата ли епрвая кнопка (вниз)
    bool touch2; // нажата ли епрвая кнопка (вверх)

    private void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
   
   public void PointerDown1() // кидаем на Event Trigger первой кнопки (вниз) в ивент PointerDown (нажата)
    {
        touch = true;
    }
    public void PointerUp1()  // кидаем на Event Trigger первой кнопки (вниз) в ивент PointerUp (не нажата)
    {
        touch = false;
    }
    public void PointerDown2() // кидаем на Event Trigger второй кнопки (верх) в ивент PointerDown (нажата)
    {
        touch2 = true;
    }
    public void PointerUp2() // кидаем на Event Trigger второй кнопки (верх) в ивент PointerDown (не нажата)
    {
        touch2 = false;
    }
   

    private void FixedUpdate()
    {

        
        if (touch == true) // если кнопка вниз нажата
        {
            rb.velocity -= moveDirection;
        } 
        if (touch2 == true) // если кнопка вверх нажата

        {
            rb.velocity += moveDirection;
        }


    }

}
```